# proving a tricky inequality

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Could someone explain the steps, from the first line of the proof to the second, i.e. how did $nx_0^{n-1}$ become $x_0^{n-1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that
$$
nx_0^{n-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x_0^{n-1}.
$$

Comment: helpful, thanks

Comment: @user144464 I'm glad I could help!